# Dynamic column names in dynamic pivot query

Tags: t-sql, dynamic, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have created a report for our Sales department, and they have what (on the surface) appears to be a simple request: if a column name contains "date_WeeklySales2017", drop the "date_" portion of the column name.

Given the following setup, how do I create a dynamic column name for COL_A in the dynamic pivot?  (I'm using SQL Server 2005 sp3)

```
CREATE TABLE #CombinedSales(
    WeekNumber int,
    WeekStart varchar(11),
    StoreNumber int,
    Address nvarchar(255),
    City nvarchar(255),
    Province varchar(2),
    WeeklySales2017 decimal(13,2),
    WeeklySales2018 decimal(13,2)
)

INSERT INTO #CombinedSales
SELECT 1, '19-Feb-2018', 1234, '123 Any Street', 'Calgary', 'AB', 12345.67, 23456.78
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '19-Feb-2018', 2345, '555 First Street', 'Toronto', 'ON', 33.25, 746.52
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '26-Feb-2018', 1234, '123 Any Street', 'Calgary', 'AB', 12345.67, 23456.78
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '26-Feb-2018', 2345, '555 First Street', 'Toronto', 'ON', 33.25, 746.52
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '05-Mar-2018', 1234, '123 Any Street', 'Calgary', 'AB', 12345.67, 23456.78
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '05-Mar-2018', 2345, '555 First Street', 'Toronto', 'ON', 33.25, 746.52
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '12-Mar-2018', 1234, '123 Any Street', 'Calgary', 'AB', 12345.67, 23456.78
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '12-Mar-2018', 2345, '555 First Street', 'Toronto', 'ON', 33.25, 746.52
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, '19-Mar-2018', 1234, '123 Any Street', 'Calgary', 'AB', 12345.67, 23456.78
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, '19-Mar-2018', 2345, '555 First Street', 'Toronto', 'ON', 33.25, 746.52

-- create the dynamic columns
DECLARE @COLUMNS nvarchar(MAX)
SELECT @COLUMNS = SUBSTRING(
                (SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(WeekStart + '_WeeklySales2017'),
                                + ', ' + QUOTENAME(WeekStart + '_WeeklySales2018')
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT WeekNumber, WeekStart FROM #CombinedSales WHERE WeekNumber IS NOT NULL ORDER BY WeekNumber) R
                ORDER BY WeekNumber DESC    -- most-recent date displayed first in pivot table report
                For XML PATH ('')
            ), 2, 10000)
PRINT @COLUMNS

-- build the dynamic pivot
DECLARE @PIVOT_SQL nvarchar(MAX)
SET @PIVOT_SQL = N'SELECT *
            FROM (
                    SELECT StoreNumber,
                            Address,
                            City,
                            Province,
                            COL_A = CAST(WeekStart as varchar(11)) + ''_'' + COL_A,
                            VALUE_A
                    FROM #CombinedSales
                    CROSS APPLY( SELECT ''WeeklySales2017'', ISNULL(WeeklySales2017, 0)
                                    UNION ALL
                                SELECT ''WeeklySales2018'', ISNULL(WeeklySales2018, 0)
                                ) c (COL_A, VALUE_A)
            ) d
            PIVOT(MAX(VALUE_A) FOR COL_A IN(' + @COLUMNS + ')
) PIV'
PRINT @PIVOT_SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @PIVOT_SQL

DROP TABLE #CombinedSales
```